# Derivative of a expectation value

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

I have a continuous random variable $x$, a function $g(x)$ that depends on that random variable, and let $f(x)$ be the density function of the $x$.

How can I calculate the following derivative of the expected value of the $g(x)$ with respect to itself?

$\frac{d}{dg(x)} \mathbb{E} (g(x)) = \frac{d}{dg(x)} \int g(x) f(x) dx$

I know that it is $-f(x)$ but I don't know why. If someone could explain it step by step I would be grateful

Comment: have you tried integration by parts?, it seems like it might work

Comment: My question came from the derivation of the first order conditions of a hidden action moral hazar problem in economics. I have found the exact same question that motivated my question in the link below. Basically, g(x) solves a maximization problem of maximizing x so, it will not depend on x, so we can "treat" it as another variable that will not depend on x. So the result easily follows, and will be f(x).
 https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/29033/first-order-conditions-in-a-moral-hazard-problem